# Why do I get FreezableCollection`1 is not a valid value in the XAML designer

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to use Nish Nishant's classes to extend the system menu of a WPF window. Nish's project is in Code Project as [An MVVM friendly approach to adding system menu entries in a WPF application](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/70568/An-MVVM-friendly-approach-to-adding-system-menu-en)

I have included Nish's source files in my project and defined some menu commands for the system menu.

This was easy and as far as I can tell it is working correctly. I am not getting a runtime error.

However, the XAML designer is showing me the error

> 'System.Windows.FreezableCollection`1[NS.MVVM.SystemMenuItem]' is not a valid value for property 'MenuItems'.

[image]

This error only appears after compiling the project. I do not get the error in Nish's sample project. I am using Visual Studio 2019 version 16.8.3. What might be causing this error message?

**EDIT**

I now know what is causing the error message, in the sense that I know what the difference is between my project and Nish's sample project.

*Nish's project targets the **x86** platform, whereas my project targeted **Any CPU**.*

This is understandable, because the code uses Win32 API functions. I have changed the target platform for my project to **x86** and the error has gone.

However, I still don't really understand why the error occurs and how it relates to the underlying issue of target platform.

Comment: based on my test, I also reproduced the problem. However, I find that it will not affect the result when we run it. If possible, I suggest it is a best choice for you to ask the question in the initial article.

Comment: Thanks Jack, I have now figured out what the difference between Nish's sample project and my project is and I have edited the question. I didn't post it as an answer, because I don't understand the cause of the specific error message. You are right that I could ask the question on Code Project, and maybe I should, but Stack Overflow is a much more active community.

Comment: Could you update your target to .Net Framework 4.8? With is version, there is no error with rebuilding.